# Why gdb is not working for this simple hello world program?

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, gdb

Code (m1.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   cout << "running m1" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

GDB Version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.2

Built using: `g++ -g m1.cpp`

Command line history:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40087b: file m1.cpp, line 6.
(gdb) r
Starting program: .../a.out

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002aaaaaac16a0 in strcmp () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb)
```

When I run without setting any breakpoints, it runs without errors.

As requested:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  strcmp () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  in check_match.12104 () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  in do_lookup_x () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#3  in _dl_lookup_symbol_x () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  in _dl_relocate_object () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#5  in dl_main () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  in _dl_sysdep_start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#7  in _dl_start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#8  in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#9  in ?? ()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce with GDB 7.12.0.

Comment: Are you suggesting I need to update GDB? The environment I am in is used by many other programmers, so I am really curious why it happens to me only.

Comment: How are you compiling your code? How did you install gdb?

Comment: Please post `bt` output.

Comment: Does the program run OK outside of GDB?

Comment: Please also show output from `(gdb) info shared`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replicate the OP's observed behavior (using the same compile and getting the same backtrace).   The behavior was persistent across a range GDBs and GCCs.   I noticed that the symptom goes away when I unset SHELL.   In my normal environment I use tcsh (version 1.15.00).   If SHELL is set, then (I believe) gdb launches using tcsh.   If I unset SHELL, gdb launches using sh.   This is enough for me to make forward progress.   I don't have a crisp explanation for what would be different in tcsh to manifest the issue but if others have the same behavior, it may shed more light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I checked that in my GNU gdb version 7.11.1. It worked really fine in it.
I first compiled the same program and built it using:

```
g++ -g m1.cpp
```

Then, ran the executable in the gdb as follows:

> gdb -q ./a.out

And did the same things you mentioned. It worked fine.
Update your gdb, and check that again and let know.